# Which OCaml database interface/library should I be using

Tags: database-connection, ocaml

I've been investigating both **Ocamldbi** and **Ocamlodbc** packages/libraries, neither of which seem to have been updating recently (which isn't necessarily an issue if the library works).

My specific initial requirements are that it be able to connect to PostgreSQL and TDS (MS-SQL) databases, but I'm developing exclusively on Linux.

Are there any other options for database access in OCaml?

Comment: Software recommendation is normally offtopic on stackoverflow. There is a posgres binding library, but I guess that if you need the ability to access different vendors RDBMs, odbc is the easier bet.

Answer (score 2):

For accessing PostgreSQL (but not MS-SQL), besides the "raw" bindings, you should give a chance to [pgocaml](http://pgocaml.forge.ocamlcore.org/), it's a very handy way to write typed queries. It comes with a functor that integrates well with the [LWT](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/) and I quickly wrote an implementation for [Async](https://github.com/janestreet/async).